# Adding column with default value to large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table with 40mil records. I need to add a new INT NOT NULL column to that table, with default value = 0

When adding this column using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD NewColumnID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT 0
```

It sets the NewColumnID to 0 for all records. When running this query on our prod table which has 40mil records, will this take a long time? Because I know doing the following takes a VERY LONG TIME:

```
UPDATE myTable SET NewColumnID = 0
```

**UPDATE: 05 Jan 2020:**

It's been a while since I've last logged into my stack-overflow account. I noticed this particular question which I posted back in 2013. I've received some bad rep for this question and I can now see why. I had to read through it several times to understand what on earth I was asking and how the answer was applicable. Seeing that it's been viewed over 6k times, perhaps it's worth (7 years later, sorry) to provide more context.

**Allow me to clarify the question:**

I was working for a banking software provider. We had various clients around the world and were rolling out a large update to our software which required a new column to be added to an existing table used by our software. This particular table was normally quite large depending on the size of the bank. The requirement was that when the column is first added, that a particular ID be assigned to all existing records, after which all new entries in the table will revert to a value of "0".

So...during the testing phase we noticed that having the following in our upgrade script took nearly an hour to process 40m records:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD NewColumnID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT 0
UPDATE myTable SET NewColumnID = 50
```

The example above will add the new column and then update all existing records with NewColumnID = 50. This is what was taking nearly an hour on the hardware which it was running on. I appreciate that this will vary drastically depending on client's infrastructure.

The reason for the question was to see if there was a faster way to accomplish the above.

**Allow me to clarify the answer:**

I completely understand why my answer makes no sense, but hopefully the following explanation will help:

Instead of adding the column and then running an update query, you assign the value that you want all the existing records to inherit by creating a CONSTRAINT with a default value that is the value you want to update it with. The creation of the column will result in this value being automatically inserted:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CompanyID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT 1 (takes about 1min to complete)
```

It was essentially "killing two birds with one stone". This query completely in roughly 1min as apposed to an hour (executed on the same server). Now that the requirement for adding a new column with a default id = x (different for each client) for all existing records, the **DEFAULT 0** constraint is restored so that all newly inserted records will assume a value of 0 if no value is passed. Hence the quote:

> Then just set the default value back to 0. Now the table will have
> CompanyID = 1 for all records. BOOM!

Apologies...this was 7 years ago and this all seems really stupid now :) but who knows, maybe this could help others with stupid requirements that requires creative hacks :)!

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: It is long and it seems normal.

Comment: You could... add the column as 'NULL' and then update the table a bit at a time

Comment: How do you not know if adding the field takes a long time when you know _updating_ it does?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Aaron for your detailed approach, but I did a quick test and the simple approach would be to do the following:

Some background. I'm adding a CompanyID to an existing large table. The ID refers to the company the record belongs to. Default value would be 0. But since this is going into an existing customers prod database, their company ID is 1. We have a generic upgrade script for all our clients, turns out a slight modification to this script for this specific customer yielding significant performance improvements.

INSTEAD OF:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CompanyID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT 0 (takes about 1min to complete)
UPDATE myTable SET CompanyID = 1 (will take over an hour)
```

I JUST DO THIS:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CompanyID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT 1 (takes about 1min to complete)
```

Then just set the default value back to 0. Now the table will have CompanyID = 1 for all records. BOOM!

Comment: It took one minute to add a column and set all 40 million rows to 1? Can you explain why you think setting the default to 1 was so much faster than setting the default to 0? I'm very confused. The answer talks about setting one default and updating all the data to a different value, while the question never mentions the value 1 at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - [I suppose they are on 2012](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/). The answer seems to address a scenario not stated in the question though.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 7):

The major problem is that this needs to write to every single row, which is heavily logged as one single transaction. One way to minimize the impact to the log (and this works best if you don't have silly 10% autogrow settings on your log file) is to break up the work as much as possible:

1. add a NULlable column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable 
    ADD NewColumnID INT CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT 0;
   ```
2. Update the rows in a batch, say 10K rows at a time (this will minimize log impact - see [this blog post for background](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes)):

   ```
   BEGIN TRANSACTION;
   SELECT 1;
   WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
   BEGIN
     COMMIT TRANSACTION;
     BEGIN TRANSACTION;

     UPDATE TOP (10000) dbo.myTable SET NewColumnID = 0;
   END
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   ```
3. Add a check constraint ([see these answers for more detail](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48872/quickly-change-null-column-to-not-null)):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable WITH CHECK
     ADD CONSTRAINT NewCol_Not_Null
     CHECK (NewColumnID IS NOT NULL);
   ```

   You can save some time by using `NOCHECK` here, but [as Martin explained in his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48936/1186), that is a one-time savings that could cost you plenty of headaches over the longer term.

This was addressed in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287954/how-do-you-add-a-not-null-column-to-a-large-table-in-sql-server), but the accepted answer there uses NOCHECK without any disclaimer about how an untrusted constraint can impact execution plans.

Answer (score 3):

No, as of SQL Server 2012, this will be instantaneous:

> Prior to SQL Server 2012 when you add a new non-NULLable column with
>   default values to an existing table a size-of data operation occurs:
>   every row in the table is updated to add the default value of the new
>   column. For small tables this is insignificant, but for large tables
>   this can be so problematic as to completely prohibit the operation.
>   But starting with SQL Server 2012 the operation is, in most cases,
>   instantaneous: only the table metadata is changed, no rows are being
>   updated.

http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes for an update query to run is completely dependent on the underlying hardware and no one here can give you a clear answer.  Updating 40 million records could take seconds or days depending on the hardware.. specifically, amount of RAM in the machine and speed of the hard drives.

That said, if a simple update like you shown takes a "VERY LONG TIME" then an alter statement is likely to take as long or longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can treat `NULL` as `0` you could add it as a sparse column - then it would not need to add any storage until you actually added a value:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable 
ADD NewColumnID int SPARSE NULL 
CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint
```

Otherwise Aaron's approach is probably the least intrusive - it will still take a long time but it can be done "online"

Answer (score -2):

It better to be drop the columns and added again. that will minimize all the overhead like any trigger or constraints over the table.