# Changing table with dependent index

Tags: sql-server

As part of a system upgrade, we need to be able to update a database structure to conform to the newest version.

I'm writing a tool to that end, but am stuck on the correct procedure for updating a column which is used in an index.

If a column which is in an index must be changed, which approach is likely to be the least problematic:

1) Disable the index, alter the column, re-enable the index

2) Drop the index, alter the column, re-create the index

There are a number of instances where this change must be applied, and I would like to reduce the overall time as much as possible, hence my preference for not recreating the index if it can be avoided.

Comment: Will you be updating clustered keys as well .When you say change the column.will you be altering only data type or change the entire column

Comment: I won't be updating any clustered keys in this case. The column in question is a varchar which will be increased from 40 chars to 100, and change to prevent nulls. Currently, nulls are permitted, although no rows contain a null in this column.

Comment: You'll need to drop/create the index or constraint rather than disable the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tests,it seems you cannot alter index columns .

```
test data:
create table idd
(
id int identity(1,1),
name char(33),
name2 varchar(40) null
)

create unique clustered index nci_id on idd(id)
create index nci_test1 on idd(name2)

--disable index
alter index nci_test1 on idd disable

--alter column
alter table idd
alter column test1 varchar(100) not null

below is the error:
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
The index 'nci_test1' is dependent on column 'test1'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 36
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN test1 failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

This is obvious since I have clustered key.so what happens if I drop clustered key and then do an alter operation on non clustered index key column,Result is same.We can alter index columns only after dropping them

```
drop index  [nci_id] on idd

--alter column
alter table idd
alter column test1 varchar(100) not null
```

I think you got some idea on what is the impact

1.We have to drop clustered key first ..heavy tlog writes,since non clustered key also have to change there pointers
2.Again we have to rebuild indexes

You can only drop them.Further I would suggest you go ahead with this approach(since either way you have to drop clustered index) of

1.Drop index
2.Alter column datatype
3.recreate index

Further try changing database recovery model to simple,so as to minimize TLOG writes prior to this operation and also add nocheck option .Below questions has some interesting answers which may help you

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48872/quickly-change-null-column-to-not-null

[How do you add a NOT NULL Column to a large table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287954/how-do-you-add-a-not-null-column-to-a-large-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know. I'm not certain I can change the recovery model (I will check permissions with the DBAs), but dropping and recreating the index does seem to be the correct course of action.

Comment: Added some more test data ,please see if this helps you,column names may not be accurate,since I tried to alter after pasting

Comment: In this instance, we don't use a clustered index at all, but the index we create is unique. I will try this on my test DB, but I'm assuming that as the key is not clustered, it should reduce the impact somewhat.

Comment: Sorry I did some mistake,it seems you cant alter index columns ,you can alter them only after dropping

Comment: This approach worked perfectly. As I didn't have any clustered indexes to rebuild, it was pretty fast too. A table with about 800,000 records was updated and he index rebuilt in around 15 seconds