# How do you deal with foreign keys, unique indexes and default constraints when using a shadow table copy and rename?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a large table in a MSSQL 2008 database, to which I need to add a new column, set a value on that new column and then make it not null.

Because the table is large, it keeps timing out on our deployment process. I read that I can use a shadow table and `SELECT INTO..`, then use `sp_rename` to replace the original table. As per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19141346/119624

The table has lots of foreign keys, indexes and constraints. I'm slightly confused as to how I should deal with those.

I assume that the process is as below. But I would appreciate it if someone could confirm whether I'm doing this in the optimum way.

Imagine this is my current table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [MyTableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeFkId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsLocked] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_IsLocked]  DEFAULT ((0)),
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MyTableId] ASC
) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_SomeFk] FOREIGN KEY([SomeFkId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SomeFk] ([SomeFkId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_SomeFk]
GO
```

I now want to add a new shadow table. Do I need to create the table with the defaults and constraints like so?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableShadow](
    [MyTableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeFkId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SomeColumn] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsLocked] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTableShadow_IsLocked]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [NewColumn] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTableShadow] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MyTableId] ASC
)WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTableShadow] WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTableShadow_SomeFk] FOREIGN KEY([SomeFkId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SomeFk] ([SomeFkId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTableShadow] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTableShadow_SomeFk]
GO
```

Then do the `SELECT INTO...`

```
SELECT  MyTable.*, MyTable.SomeColumn -- copying value
 INTO    MyTableShandow 
 FROM    MyTable
```

Then do the rename:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'MyTable', 'MyTableOld'
EXEC sp_rename 'MyTableShadow', 'MyTable'
```

Then do the drop:

```
DROP TABLE MyTableOld
```

Then rename the constraints and foreign keys:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'PK_MyTableShadow', 'PK_MyTable', 'object' -- PK
EXEC sp_rename 'FK_MyTableShadow_SomeFk', 'FK_MyTable_SomeFk', 'object' -- FK
EXEC sp_rename 'DF_MyTableShadow_IsLocked', 'DF_MyTable_IsLocked', 'object' -- DF
```

Is that the correct process, or is there another easier way? (I have a table that has a lot of FKs and constraints, so I'm trying to reduce the pain!

Comment: Backup the database.  Script out all constraints, keys and triggers.  Drop all constraints, keys, and triggers.  Rename the old table.  Create the new table.  Populate the new table; SSIS may be the quickest.  Add constraints, keys, trigger. This is how I would do it if I could afford the down time on the database.

Comment: I need to run this as a script as part of a database migration, so SSIS is sadly excluded. Interesting though, just dropping them all first, then recreating them. IS it quicker to add the constraints and keys after the table is populated, or before?

Comment: Going table to table, your data load will be much quicker without indexes and constraints.  Indexes require writes for the data and then for the Index, except for the Clustering key, in which case the data is the index.  Constraints will require a check on the data as it is inserted to make sure the constraint isn't violated.  This should be unnecessary during the load if the constraints haven't been violated already. One thing that hasn't been mentioned is IDENTITY columns.  You will need to be careful if these columns are or are part of your keys.  You will need to manage that if using.