# Adding new NOT NULL column to existing database

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2016

Lets say I have a system that has a person table:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DOB       DATE NOT NULL
)
```

If we want to update the system after it has been in place for a number of years and we now want to also capture the person's address (by means of a new NVARCHAR column called Address which is `NOT NULL`)

Therefore we want all new records to be `NOT NULL` but we don't have any data for the old records so they would have to be NULL

What is the best way to do this? We cannot add a `NOT NULL` column because it would be NULL for all the existing records.

Is the best way to add the column and allow NULLS, add some placeholder value (EG '.') to the existing records, then alter the column to be NULL?

Or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: You can't have different constraints for different rows.  Depending on the RDBMS, however, you may be able to have complex constraints similar in functionality to `created_datetime < '2018-02-01' OR address IS NOT NULL`.  So, which RDBMS are you using?  *(Including which version.)*

Comment: Updated tags (using SQL server 2016)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add a NOT NULL Column to a large table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287954/how-do-you-add-a-not-null-column-to-a-large-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: You want a placeholder value to use when you have *missing information*? That sounds suspiciously like a conventional description of `null`. So why invent a *different* placeholder that then has to be specially coded for?

Comment: Please be bit more specific. Logically, does every user have an address?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
It is indeed a NULL that I want to display against the existing rows (as I don't have those addresses) However, I want to enforce that all records going forward MUST Have a value in the Address field. To do this I would need to add a NOT NULL constraint, however that is impossible as the existing records address are NULL

Comment: @DamirSudarevic this is a hypothetical scenario and I have used Person and Address for simplicity in describing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a new `NOT NULL` column without assigning non-NULL values to existing rows (via a default constraint). However, you can add a `NULL` column and ensure only `NOT NULL` values going forward by specifying a check constraint that prohibits `NULL` values along with the `NOCKECK` option so that existing data are not validated:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person
(
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DOB       DATE NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Person (FirstName, LastName , DOB)
    VALUES(N'foo', N'bar', '20010101');
GO
--add new column and CHECK constraint with NOCHECK
ALTER TABLE dbo.Person WITH NOCHECK
    ADD Address nvarchar(50) NULL
    CONSTRAINT CK_Person_Address CHECK (Address IS NOT NULL);
GO
--this fails due to check constraint violation
INSERT INTO dbo.Person (FirstName, LastName , DOB)
    VALUES(N'foo2', N'bar2', '20020101');
GO
--this succeeds
INSERT INTO dbo.Person (FirstName, LastName , DOB, Address)
    VALUES(N'foo2', N'bar2', '20020101', N'non-null address');
GO
```

This method provides the proper NULL semantics for existing persons that have no addresses yet guarantee the desired data integrity for new persons.